# jQuery sortable move up/down multiple <options> in <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to move the  in  using the following code but when i select multiple options it doesn't work right

How can I move multiple elements up and down?

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  \$().ready(function() { 
//for moving elements up and down
\$('.up-button').click(function(){

 before = \$('#select2 option:selected').prev();
    \$('#select2 option:selected').insertBefore(before);
    });

\$('.down-button').click(function(){
   after = \$('#select2 option:selected').next();
    \$('#select2 option:selected').insertAfter(after);
}); 
   });  
 </script>
```

You can find the reference at [JS live code](http://jsbin.com/etOcAHu/3/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed up/down logic a bit:

```
$('.up-button').click(function(){
  $('#select2 option:selected:first-child').prop("selected", false);
  before = $('#select2 option:selected:first').prev();
    $('#select2 option:selected').detach().insertBefore(before);

});

$('.down-button').click(function(){
  $('#select2 option:selected:last-child').prop("selected", false);
  after = $('#select2 option:selected:last').next();
    $('#select2 option:selected').detach().insertAfter(after);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/etOcAHu/15/edit)

Comment: this works fine but the last element is deleted on click down

Comment: @R thanks for solution. It works fine with one object selected but when multiple selected the others get deleted...

Answer (score 2):

use `.first()` and `.last()`, because you're selecting multiple elements

```
//for moving elements up and down
$('.up-button').click(function(){
 before = $('#select2 option:selected').first().prev();
    $('#select2 option:selected').insertBefore(before);

});

$('.down-button').click(function(){
   after = $('#select2 option:selected').last().next();
    $('#select2 option:selected').insertAfter(after);
});
```

Comment: solution needs .not(":last-child") / .not(":first-child") fix